# is it possible to download images from a website really fast when using JAVA

Tags: java, image, web, download

suppose we have this URL called

"mysite.com"

in this site we have a directory called images that has about 200 .PNG pictures

I want to make a program that scans through these pictures one by one(you can predict the picture's URL if you know the previous picture's URL) and then I want to display this image on my JFrame

what I initially thought of doing was, since I know the URL, why don't I just scan through all the different image urls, and then do this?

```
  Image image = ImageIO.read(url); hasImage.setIcon(new
  ImageIcon(image));
```

now

```
 hasImage
```

is a JLabel where I use the image that I just downloaded from the URL

and

```
url
```

is an object of class URL

so, everytime in a loop I find the new URL, and I call the function that has the 2 lines of code that I just posted above, in order to update the image on my label

note that these 2 lines are inside a button ActionListener, so that everytime I click on the button, the next image will be displayed

there is 1 major problem here.

when I want to display the next image, it takes some time to create the new url object, download the image, and then display it on my label, which is kind of annoying especially if you're in a hurry and want to display the images really fast...

now, I thought of another implementation, why not just download all the images, save them somewhere locally and then scan through the directory where you stored the images and display them each time the button is clicked?

ok I did this, but the problem is that it takes more than a minute to download all the images
after that it works smoothly, really fast

so here the big problem is that it takes so much time to download the images, so it's basically the previous implementation, but in this one instead of waiting a little bit when I press the button, I kind of wait for everything to get downloaded, which takes the same time...

my question is, how can I make it be faster? if it would download all the images in less than 5 seconds I would be satisfied

here is the function I'm using in order to save the images

```
   private void saveImages() {
    Image image;
    int ID = 1;
    String destFile = "destFolder" + ID + ".png";

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
        ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "png", new File(destFile));
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

    while (ID < 200) {
        try {
            String path = url.getPath();

            String[] token = path.split("-");
            String[] finalToken = token[2].split("\\.");
            ID = Integer.parseInt(finalToken[0]);
            url = new URL("http://somesite/images/" + (ID + 1) + ".png");


            destFile = "C:\\...\\destFolder\\" + ID + ".png";
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
            ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "png", new File(destFile));

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "URL is not in the correct form", "Malformed URL",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Images were loaded successfully",
            "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

EDIT: Btw I'm really sorry about the code, it's kind of messy, it's just the first thing I typed.... I will change it later for the better but I hope you get the idea of what problem I'm facing right now :)

Answer (score 3):

Neither Java or the implementation is the issue, it's the speed of your connection. Either you download all images that the application requires (which takes some time, and is pointless if the images aren't viewed) or you load them as they're clicked.

If you want to make it seem a little quicker, you can start loading the images into a local database or the filesystem (like a cache). That obviously has its drawbacks as it will only make loading times faster once a picture has been loaded once, and it's often ideal to not have a very large cache.

You can also load the five or so next and previous images when just viewing one image, which will make it seem faster to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading 200 images from the web is always going to take some time. What you need to do to speed this up is

1. To avoid downloading the images in the event dispatch thread: it blocks the UI while downloading. The images should be downloaded in a separate, background thread.
2. To have two threads downloading images simultaneously. You could download more in parallel, but most of the web servers refuse more than 2 concurrent connections from the same host.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest loading images in the background and having them appear as soon as they are loaded, that way your UI will be responsive. When you go to a particular image you can automatically load the next ones in anticipation as well.

Here's a rather green dry-coded (not actually tried to compile) attempt at this, that should demonstrate the idea. (Forgive the tight coupling and rather mashed up responsibilities in the classes. Also, it rather cavalier about the unboundedness of the `imageBuffer`, and there is no offload to disk).

```
class ImageManager {
  private ExecutorService asyncLoader = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  private HashMap<Integer, Image> imageBuffer = new HashMap<Integer, Image>();
  private final int PRELOAD = 2;
  private String baseUrl;
  public ImageManager(String baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  }
  public void loadImageAndUpdateLabel(final int idx, final JLabel label) {
    asyncLoader.execute(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        loadSync(idx);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageBuffer.get(idx)));
          label.setText(null);
        });
      }
    });
    triggerAsyncPreload(idx);        
  }
  public void triggerAsyncPreload(int idx) {
    for (int i=idx-PRELOAD; i<idx+PRELOAD; i++) {
      if (i>0) {
        loadAsync(i);
      }
    }
  }
  public synchronized void loadSync(int idx) {
    if (imageBuffer.get(idx) == null) {
      imageBuffer.put(idx, ImageIO.read(new URL(baseUrl, idx+".png")));
    }
  }
  public void loadAsync(final int idx) {
    asyncLoader.execute(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        loadSync(idx);
      }
    });
  }
}

class ... {
  ...
  private int currentImageIdx = 0;
  private ImageManager imageManager = new ImageManager("http://site.com/images/");
  private JLabel label = new JLabel();
  private JButton nextImageButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Next image") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      currentImageIdx++;
      label.setIcon(null);
      label.setText("Loading image "+currentImageIdx);
      imageManager.loadImageAndUpdateLabel(currentImageIdx, label);
    }
  });
  ...
}
```